# Looking for pre-1975 youth Sci-fi book about 3-4 kids who build a rocket and launch it in the woods while at camp

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

It was a book about three or four kids who build a rocket with themselves as the payload. I think they did it at a camp in the woods but I'm not sure. I don't even remember if it got off the ground. I thought is was called something like "Tree-Two-One Liftoff!", but the only thing I can find close to that is a Regent reader book that I know is not the correct one. Can anyone here help me to find the actual title so I can try to buy one for my grand kids?

Comment: What kind of payload was the rocket carrying? Did the kids themselves go up in it? And what was the rocket's destination?

Comment: It could be _[The Wonderful Flight to the Mushroom Planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wonderful_Flight_to_the_Mushroom_Planet)_ from 1954, about two boys from a place called Pacific Grove who build a rocket from scrap wood. This was also the subject of [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/93072/4495).

Comment: Nope, but it sounds fun too. It was a book I read in my Junior High Library in 7th grade. They tor down the school in my 9th grade and I wasn't quick enough to ask if I could have it when they closed the school

Comment: I don't remember any payload other than the kids, but I don't even remember if it got off the ground.

Comment: :) I assume that 1975 was when 7th grade was for you?

Comment: no, 9th. But it was an older book at that time. So I guess it had to be pre-1973...ish

Comment: I know the book you're talking about. It's about three boys who build and launch rockets in a swampy area near their town... and the locals oppose them. I remember at the end the townspeople come around and there's a final launch, and a banner is deployed that's supposed to say "BLAST YOU ALL" but the T falls off, and it's mis-read as "BLAS [BLESS] YOU ALL. And the title is something like 3-2-1 Blastoff or something like that. Definitely from the 1960's, early 1970's.

Comment: Was the book or story part of a series, or could you be remembering just a single chapter?  This sounds like the kind of thing that *The Mad Scientists Club* might have included, except I don't recall a rocket launch in any of the three books.

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for a similar book and it ended up being "Blast-Off" by Bruce Cassiday. Maybe it's your book as well?

[image: Blast-Off! - Book Cover]

The inside flap text:

> "T minus 10 seconds...9...8..." came the voice. "This is it," Gene Long thought. In 8 more seconds, the Starbound would take off. The other members of the Hillstown High School Science Club were grouped around him, intent on the rocket they had designed and built themselves. "7...6...5..." So much effort had cone into this firing! There had been a team to get together, designs to draw up, fuel to decide upon. When hatred flared up between two members of the team, Gene had gotten them working together again. And now, their reward.... "4..3...2..1.." Gene reached for the red firing button. "Blast Off!" Gene pushed the button....

Comment: Perhaps you can edit your answer to add why you think it's the one the question is seeking -- how the book you found matches the question?

Answer (score 2):

*[Rocket Ship Galileo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocket_Ship_Galileo)* was a 1947 young-adult book by Heinlein about three kids building a rocket, but they do it with their uncle's help, and in the desert. They make it to the moon and discover a Nazi camp up there. It seems a very tenuous match, but I figure I'll mention it on the off chance that you misremember the details.

Comment: Thanks, I know it's not Heinlein. I have nearly all of his. Great stuff. This was a group of three or four kids who build a rocket ship at their camp in the woods.