# Book Series for MG/Children - About Kind/Gentle Alien Professor/Engineer Working in Basement Laboratory

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens, childrens-novel

A Series of Books for Children / MG
Read in 1977 / 5th grade
   Main character is a kind/gentle/smart alien professor/engineer doing experiments in his basement laboratory… solving mysteries, I think there was some type of garden?
A neighbor child is his companion and keeps his alien secret, or something like that?
   Mystery
   Please help me remember the name, or a clue to finding the book series~
Thank you!

Comment: Except for the alien part, it sounds like the [*Danny Dunn*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danny_Dunn) series.

Comment: What is MG? Middle… Group?

Answer (score 2):

This might be the "Mushroom Planet" series (published starting in 1954) by Eleanor Cameron, previously asked about and answered on this site at [Space travel with spores or mushrooms](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/93072/space-travel-with-spores-or-mushrooms) and [And now, for something completely different: The mushrooms are among us](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/70827/and-now-for-something-completely-different-the-mushrooms-are-among-us).

Per the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wonderful_Flight_to_the_Mushroom_Planet), the kind alien Professor would be Mr. Tyco Bass. The "garden" would be Basidium-X, "a small, verdant world covered in soft moss and tree-size mushrooms" in orbit around Earth (but never noticed).

The larger series is [described pretty well at a fan site](http://peyre.x10.mx/MushroomPlanet/index.htm); you may recognize some of the cover shots.